# Difference between different types of SQL?

Tags: sql, database

What are the differences between all of the different types of SQL? I hear of PostgreSQL, SQLite, MySQL, SQL, .... What are the differences between them?

Comment: SQL what? SQL language dialects or SQL "servers`" types?

Comment: I'm rather new to the field so i'm not sure...

Comment: Real answer is found here: https://www.quora.com/Why-there-are-so-many-types-of-SQL-What-is-the-difference-between-all-of-them

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> **[SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)** is Structured Query Language is a
>   database computer language designed
>   for managing data in relational
>   database management systems (RDBMS).
>
> **[PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL)** is an object-relational
>   database management system
>   (ORDBMS).[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) It is released under a
>   BSD-style license and is thus free
>   software. As with many other
>   open-source programs, PostgreSQL is
>   not controlled by any single company,
>   but has a global community of
>   developers and companies to develop
>   it.
>
> **[SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite)** is an ACID-compliant embedded
>   relational database management system
>   contained in a relatively small (~225
>   KB[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)) C programming library. The
>   source code for SQLite is in the
>   public domain.
>
> **[MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)** (pronounced /maɪˌɛskjuːˈɛl/[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)
>   My S-Q-L, or "My sequel"
>   /maɪˈsiːkwəl/) is a relational
>   database management system (RDBMS)[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL)
>   which has more than 6 million
>   installations. [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) MySQL stands for
>   "My Structured Query Language". The
>   program runs as a server providing
>   multi-user access to a number of
>   databases.

Comment: One small other question: do you say PostgreSQL like this? "Postgres-ql"?

Comment: @RCIX, http://www.postgresql.org/community/survey.33

Comment: This answers the question but it's reaaaallly surfacey...

Comment: I've heard POST G R E SQL, and postgres-ql before.

Comment: I've only ever heard "Postgres", but I assume that's because it was clear from context and isn't how it's supposed to be pronounced...

Answer (score 12):

If you want to know about different dialects of [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) (*Structured Query Language*)

 Have a look here :

> http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_dialects_reference

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 11):

PostgreSQL, SQLite, MySQL, MS SQL are just [database management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbms) from **different vendors**

Answer (score 6):

[Comparison of relational database management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems)

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL, SQLite, MySQL, MSSQL, Sybase = relational database management systems (RDBMSes).

SQL, TSQL = the actual languages used by the aforementioned database systems. Although (in theory) SQL is standardised, in practice each vendor has their own "extensions" (variations) on the language - which means that SQL written for MySQL may not work under Sybase, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Different Vendors= Different Ideas and Concepts.
Like every other Programming Problem...every developer solutes it differently and thats great. :-)
Learing about this little differences or sometimes big "Messed up" is good.