# Full list of differences between different versions of SQL (MySQL, SQL Server, etc?)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I was wondering about the differences between dialects of SQL. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495519/list-of-differences-between-sql-databases) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326318/difference-between-different-types-of-sql) but either I couldn't understand the answers or they weren't enough. I'm relatively new to SQL, and so I can't really find a comprehensible answer.

Comment: If you are new to SQL, the differences probably aren't relevant.  You can learn on any database and then start to understand the differences as you become more proficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a *coder* level, you generally want to be aware of ANSI sql and track how the databases differ from that.

Regular select/insert/delete/update commands are fairly portable.
Generally speaking, things that will be different are non-core-syntax aspects like:

- functions.  any getXXX(), rtrim(xxx) are, more often that not, vendor specific.  Anyway, functions tend to mess up index use as well, so best used sparingly.
- update/from, delete/from.  Those are, I believe, vendor-specific.
- dates.  are surprisingly non-portable, with everyone and his dog having a different way to specify date masks for example.
- procedural/trigger extensions.  Any procedural language is likely to have a lot of scope for vendor-specificity.
- case sensitivity. some databases are all UPPERCASE, some all lowercase, some are insensitive.
- any "extra stuff" in a query that isn't a column.  Things like LIMIT, rownum, rowid are generally vendor-specific.
- old outer join syntax, like 'e.department_id = d.department_id(+)'
- "complicated queries".  Let's say you want to flush out order lines for orders that have been entirely fullfilled.

  delete from order_lines where not exists 
    (select 1 from order_lines s
    where s.order_no = order_lines.order_no
    and s.status <> 'fullfilled')

  DB2, in the past at least, would have likely complained about a "correlated subquery", which basically boils down to referencing a table which you are in the process of modifying, order_lines in this case.

Basically, you should kinda be OK if you stick to older ANSI SQL.  I worked on PeopleSoft for years and it was deeply drilled into us to write multi-db sql (DB2/Oracle/MSSQL, etc...), without resorting to writing vendor-specific code (i.e. 1 query for Oracle, 1 for MSSQL...).  It can be done, just requires a suspicious mindset about anything that looks like vendor shortcuts & sql enhancements, regardless of how attractive they are.

For specific queries, head off to [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and you can test a number of cases.  And, unfortunately, I don't know of any books that aim to teach actual, as opposed to proposed, ANSI SQL.   And, **even more unfortunately, the worthies @ ANSI SQL standards have not seen fit to make their standard freely available**.

At an *admin* level, such as all the DDL for create table/index/..., there are way more differences to be aware of, starting with datatypes.